# Unit testing Apollo, errorring on mutation mock

Tags: reactjs, testing, apollo

I'm trying to mock out a graphql mutation for my unit tests. I'm using the MockedProvider but I'm getting the error: 'UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No more mocked responses for the query: mutation LoginMutation'

I've done a lot of googling, and copy pasted everything into one file so that there can be no issues with imports

```
const LOGIN_MUTATION = gql`
    mutation LoginMutation($email: String!, $password: String!) {
    login(email: $email, password: $password) {
      token
      user {
        name
      }
    }
  }
`;

const mocks = [
  {
    request: {
      query: LOGIN_MUTATION,
      variables: { email: 'test@test.com', password: 'password' },
    },
    result: {
      data: {
        login: {
          token: 'fakeToken',
          user: {
            name: 'Testy McTestface'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

describe('LoginForm', () => {
  let wrapper;
  let store;

  beforeEach(() => {
    store = mockStore(initialState);
  });

  it('triggers the doLogin action creator after the graphql call', () => {
    const mockDoLogin = jest.fn()
    let mockedWrapper = mount(
      <MockedProvider mocks={mocks} addTypename={false}>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <LoginForm doLogin={mockDoLogin} />
        </Provider>
      </MockedProvider>,
    );
    mockedWrapper.find('#loginButton').simulate('click')
    expect(mockDoLogin).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  })
});
```

I expect this test to pass (the tag searched for on the wrapper is the correct one) but I get the error described above, so I'm assuming the issue is with my mock but it looks good to me?

Sorry if this is something ridiculously obvious but I've been staring at it for hours now.

Comment: Could please try to add the `__typename` to your mocks, this fixed the problem in most of our cases.

Comment: Hi @AndreasKöberle could you go into a bit more detail?

Comment: In your response from apollo server every entity should have a `__typename` attribute, if you miss this in your mock you will get the `No more mocked responses for the query` error.

Comment: I thought that adding 'addTypename={false}' to my mocked provider meant I wouldn't have to do that?

Comment: @AndreasKöberle, were you using MockedProvider or another way of mocking the QraphQL server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you like to give a shot to [easygraphql-tester](https://github.com/EasyGraphQL/easygraphql-tester)? It'll mock the query for you, but also, if you want to set some fixture you can set them too!

You might pass the schema in order to use it!

```
import EasyGraphQLTester from 'easygraphql-tester'

const tester = new EasyGraphQLTester(schema)

const LOGIN_MUTATION = gql`
    mutation LoginMutation($email: String!, $password: String!) {
    login(email: $email, password: $password) {
      token
      user {
        name
      }
    }
  }
`;

const mocks = [
  {
    request: {
      query: LOGIN_MUTATION,
      variables: { email: 'test@test.com', password: 'password' },
    },
    result: tester.mock({
      query: LOGIN_MUTATION,
      variables: { email: 'test@test.com', password: 'password' }
    })
  }
]
```